# HERE GET Request Python

Tags: python, api, here-api

Was wondering if there's a way for me to send out multiple long and lat cords in the destination and arrival in the HERE api instead of just individual long and lat. For example in the origin and destination param, I want to input a list of long and lat.

```
import request
    url = """https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?origin=47.584247,11.055542&origin=67.584247,12.055542&transportMode=pedestrian&destination=47.589299,11.060172&destination=63.584247,11.055542&return=polyline,elevation&apikey=apikey"""
    response = requests.get(url, verify = False)
    j = response.json()
```

Comment: When you use the code that you show, does it work? If it works, what do you find inadequate about it? If it doesn't work, what happens, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: the code that i have works but its only pulling from a single long-lat pair, I want to pass in a list of long-lat pair in the api

Comment: Okay, so did you try reading the documentation to see if that is supported? What do you want to *happen* when you supply multiple long-lat pairs - what should the result look like, compared to how it looks for a single pair? Can you solve the problem by just making a separate request for each pair? If not, why not?

Comment: just call one request to pull out a data from a list of cords because its cheaper than to call multiple requests lol

Comment: you can read the [docs](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/api-reference-swagger.html). It clearly says `Exactly one place`

Comment: bro chill.. i did read and told my team member that but they still want me to look for a way to do it :'(

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer the examples in [multiplewaypoint](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/via.html). Also please use our router tool [Routerdemo](https://refclient.ext.here.com/#url=https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?origin=33.265011,74.289070&routingMode=short&transportMode=car&destination=32.7185614,74.8580917&vehicle%5BhovOccupancy%5D=0&return=polyline,actions,instructions,summary&apikey=) to validate.

Thanks.